# Is there a reason why the existing converters for `spring-kafka` and `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` are different?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

In `KafkaProperties` provided by `spring-kafka`, the de/serializer of producer and consumer is `String{Des/S}serializer`.

However, when using `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka`, it is changed to `ByteArray{Des/S}erializer` by `KafkaBinderEnvironmentPostProcessor`. Is there a reason to take this as default? Or is there a reason to have different settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The byte array (de)serializers are more efficient when converting to/from JSON (which is normally the case with Spring Cloud Stream); it avoids an unnecessary conversion from `byte[]` to `String` (and vice-versa) before/after JSON conversion. Jackson can convert directly to/from `byte[]` which is the native Kafka value type.

Boot chose String because it provides a much simpler "getting started" experience.

Typical applications (other than SCSt) will use more sophisticated implementations (JSON, Avro, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was confused by changing the default settings. :)